# igraph how to get edge ids along the shortest paths

Tags: c, shortest-path, igraph, edges

I have a graph with multiple shortest paths and want to retrieve the ids of the vertices and the ids of the edges:

`igraph_get_all_shortest_paths(...)` computes only the list of the vertices.

Isn't

```
igraph_get_shortest_paths(&g, &vertices, &edges, from,igraph_vss_1(to), IGRAPH_ALL);
```

supposed to do that ?

When I run:

```
igraph_t g1;
igraph_vector_t v1;
int ret;

/* Create a graph */
igraph_vector_init(&v1, 0);

igraph_create(&g1, &v1, 0, 0);
igraph_add_vertices(&g1, 1, 0);
igraph_add_vertices(&g1, 1, 0);
igraph_add_vertices(&g1, 1, 0);
igraph_add_vertices(&g1, 1, 0);
igraph_add_vertices(&g1, 1, 0);

igraph_add_edge(&g1,0,1);
igraph_add_edge(&g1,0,2);
igraph_add_edge(&g1,2,3);
igraph_add_edge(&g1,1,3);
igraph_add_edge(&g1,0,4);
igraph_add_edge(&g1,4,3);
igraph_add_edge(&g1,4,3);
igraph_add_edge(&g1,4,3);

igraph_vector_ptr_t verts;
igraph_vector_ptr_init(&verts, 2);


igraph_vector_ptr_t eds;
igraph_vector_ptr_init(&eds, 2);

igraph_vector_t v2;
igraph_vector_init(&v2,2);
VECTOR(v2)[0] = 3;
VECTOR(v2)[1] = 3;

igraph_vs_t tovs = igraph_vss_vector(&v2);

igraph_get_shortest_paths(&g1, &verts, &eds, 0, tovs , IGRAPH_ALL);
igraph_destroy(&g1);
```

I get error: igraph_vector_clear: Assertion `v != ((void *)0)' failed

Comment: Changed the `c++` tag to `c`, igraph is a c library.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is supposed to do that. From the docs at [the igraph homepage](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/ch13s02.html#igraph_get_shortest_paths):

[...]

`vertices`:

The result, the ids of the vertices along the paths. This is a pointer vector, each element points to a vector object. These should be initialized before passing them to the function, which will properly clear and/or resize them and fill the ids of the vertices along the geodesics from/to the vertices. Supply a null pointer here if you don't need these vectors. Normally, either this argument, or the edges should be non-null, but no error or warning is given if they are both null pointers.

`edges`:

The result, the ids of the edges along the paths. This is a pointer vector, each element points to a vector object. These should be initialized before passing them to the function, which will properly clear and/or resize them and fill the ids of the vertices along the geodesics from/to the vertices. Supply a null pointer here if you don't need these vectors. Normally, either this argument, or the vertices should be non-null, but no error or warning is given if they are both null pointers.

[...]

So the vertices along the paths are returned in `vertices` and the edges along the paths are returned in `edges`.

### Edit

I see you added some source code. As the docs says, the vectors in the pointer vector(s) must be allocated and initialized before calling this function. This is somewhat strange, because it is different from other igraph functions, but still, this is why you get the error message.

Comment: As you can see from the code there are 3 shortest paths that go through the same 3 vertices. I was hopping to get the different sets of edges that represent these paths. But I get 'igraph_vector_clear: Assertion "v != ((void *)0)" failed'

Comment: Isn't this how I should init/alloc the ptr vectors: igraph_vector_ptr_t verts;
igraph_vector_ptr_init(&verts, 2);
igraph_vector_ptr_t eds;
igraph_vector_ptr_init(&eds, 2);

Comment: VECTOR(vecs)[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(igraph_vector_t)); ?

Comment: No just that, but in the `igraph_vector_ptr_t` you must have pointers to `igraph_vector_t` objects and these should be initialized, too. See [the example that comes with igraph](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~igraph/igraph/0.6-main/view/head:/examples/simple/igraph_get_shortest_paths.c)

Comment: The example program doesn't compile:  igraph_vector_init(VECTOR(vecs)[i], 0); invalid arguments

Comment: It works with: igraph_vector_init((igraph_vector_t*)VECTOR(vecs)[i], 0);

Comment: All example programs are checked before each release on several platforms, so unless you are using some exotic platform, that should not happen. You did not give any details, so I can only guess that you used a C++ compiler, whereas igraph is a C library. Please try compiling it with a C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The

> igraph_get_shortest_paths(&g, &vecs, &evecs, 0, vs, IGRAPH_OUT)

doesn't seem to return multiple shortest paths to one vertex. To be more explicit in the case you have more than one shortest path to/from one vertex the method returns only **ONE PATH** (ignoring the rest)!!!! Not multiple paths to/from one vertex as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Well, the documentation says: "If there is more than one geodesic between two vertices, this function gives only one of them." (http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/ch13s02.html#igraph_get_shortest_paths) So this is actually documented. In fact, this is all what it says, apart from discussing what the arguments are.

Comment: Take a look at the `get_all_shortest_paths()` function to get all shortest paths. (http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/ch13s02.html#igraph_get_all_shortest_paths)

Comment: `get_all_shortest_paths()` retrieves only the list of nodes ids I also need to get the ids of the edges also. In some cases I have multiple edges connecting two vertices. Is there a way to get all the shortest paths from one node to another by retrieving the nodes ids and the edges ids.

Comment: One way is to take the ids of the vertices and then individually query the edges between them. Probably best using `igraph_get_eids_multi()`.

Comment: So lets say I have 7 paths that go through the same 3 vertices. I want to identify the ids of the edges that compose the respective paths. How can I do that ? For `igraph_get_eids_multi()` to work I need to know the nb of edges connecting the two vertices so I can know how many times I should inlcude them in the &pairs parameter. I really don;t see how I can do this.